# c function returns 2 values but only 1 is passed to the statement

Tags: c

Can you help me explain how this gives 3 as a result?

```
int main()
{
  int k = fun(125, 35);

    printf("%d",k);

  return 0;
}

int fun(int x, int y){

      if (y <= 1) return x;

      else if (y > x / y) return fun(y, x / y);

      else return fun(x / y, y);
}
```

Comment: Everyone can post the code into the question, newbies included. Just paste the code, select the code, click the code button.  The code button looks like this: `{}`

Comment: Integer division truncates. So if `x` is an `int` with value 125, and `y` is an `int` with value 35, then `x/y` is 3.

Comment: yea i understand that, but what is the role of y before x/y. I mean in return fun(y, x / y); what the first y do? I know that return returns only 1 value..Does it return y and the return x/y so it overwrites the previous return?

Comment: @ZikZik you got to read about functions and then recursive function.

Comment: It's calling the function recursively, and returning whatever the recursive call returned. Adding `printfs` to the code, or stepping through the code with a debugger might help you understand it better.

Comment: It's called recursion.  In the statement `return fun(y, x / y);` the function `fun` calls itself, passing `y` as the first argument and `x / y` as the second.  The new invocation of `fun` runs and returns a value.  Then the calling invocation returns that value (this is known as tail recursion).

Comment: What do you mean by "c function returns 2 values"? At that point I can only think "No, it does not. C functions always return a single value." Copmared to that, the other question is minor, what you mean by "only one is passed to the statement".

Answer (score 3):

The first time your program calls the `fun(int x,int y)` , it will call `fun(125,35)`.
Since 35>1 and 35>(125/35), thus your function will return `fun(y,x/y)` i.e. `fun(35,3)`.
Now, since 3>1 but 3<(35/3), thus it will return `fun(x/y,y)` i.e. `fun(11,3)`. Now, 3>1 and 3=(11/3), so it will return `fun(x/y,y)` i.e. `fun(3,3)`. Again 3>1  and 3>(3/3), thus it will call `fun(3,1)`. Now `y==1`, thus the function will return value of x i.e 3.

Answer (score 1):

`return fun(y, x / y);` returns one value. That value is the result of calling `fun` with the two arguments `y` and `x / y`.

This use of a function within itself is called recursion. The possible values with which `fun` is called are divided into *base cases* and *general cases*. In a *base case*, the function is computed in a simple way. For example, in this function, when `y <= 1`, the function returns `x`.

In *general cases*, the function is computed by calling itself with different arguments. Usually, the different arguments are reduced or simplified in some way (although convoluted cases in which arguments grow larger or more complicated before eventually reaching bases cases are also possible). In this function, the arguments are reduced by replacing `x` and `y` with either `y` and `x/y` or with `x/y` and `y`. In either case, at least one of the arguments has been made smaller by dividing it by `y`, which we know is greater than 1 at this point.

Eventually, the function will call itself with the second argument reduced to a value less than or equal to 1, at which point the function will return the first argument, and the entire sequence of calls will wrap up by returning this value.